# Check and correct my code. (I'm a beginner)

Tags: java

Can someone please help me correct my code ? It is created to calculate housing loan (UMI), the coding is correct but it doesn't show the output completely. After "Enter loan duration", it shows a box. Also is there another way to set the variables in `class Variables` ?

```
package assignment.pkg2;
import java.util.Scanner;//for Scanner
import java.text.DecimalFormat;//for using decimal format

class Variables{ //set the variables
    private double p, r, n;

    public void setVarP (double amount){
        this.p = amount;
    }
    public void setVarR (double rate){
        this.r = rate;
    }
    public void setVarN (int duration){
        this.n = duration;
    }
    public double getVarP(){
        return p;
    }
    public double getVarR(){
        return r;
    }
    public double getVarN(){
        return n;
    }
}

class EMIcalc{ //the calculating part
    private double monthlyPay, pow;
   Variables var = new Variables();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void getPay(){
        pow = Math.pow (1+(var.getVarR()/12), - var.getVarN());
        monthlyPay = var.getVarP() * ( (var.getVarR()/12) / (1 - pow) );

        DecimalFormat Dformat = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
        System.out.println(Dformat.format(monthlyPay));
    }

}

public class Assignment2 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Variables var1 = new Variables();
            EMIcalc calc = new EMIcalc();
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Enter your loan amount");
            var1.setVarP(scanner.nextDouble());

            System.out.println("Enter interest rate");
            var1.setVarR(scanner.nextDouble());

            System.out.println("Enter loan duration");
            var1.setVarN(scanner.nextInt());

            calc.getPay();
        }
}
```

Comment: You should consider the stack Echange code review to do that. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Code review guidelines say not to ask in case of incorrect results. This might be better here, as the problem is that Op confused two different objects as being the same.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

Your are setting the values into `var1`, but the `calc` looks at its internal `var` field, which is a different object. You could just replace `var1.set...` by `calc.var.set...`.

Or you could merge your `Variables` and `EMIcalc` classes into one.

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for this?

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Variables { //set the variables
    private double p, r, n;

    public double getVarP() {
        return p;
    }
    public void setVarP(double amount) {
        this.p = amount;
    }
    public double getVarR() {
        return r;
    }
    public void setVarR(double rate) {
        this.r = rate;
    }
    public double getVarN() {
        return n;
    }
    public void setVarN(int duration) {
        this.n = duration;
    }
}

class EMIcalc { //the calculating part
    Variables var = new Variables();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    private double monthlyPay, pow;

    public void getPay() {
        pow = Math.pow(1 + (var.getVarR() / 12), -var.getVarN());
        monthlyPay = var.getVarP() * ((var.getVarR() / 12) / (1 - pow));
        DecimalFormat Dformat = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
        System.out.println(Dformat.format(monthlyPay));
    }
}

public class Assignment2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EMIcalc calc = new EMIcalc();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your loan amount");
        calc.var.setVarP(scanner.nextDouble());
        System.out.println("Enter interest rate");
        calc.var.setVarR(scanner.nextDouble());
        System.out.println("Enter loan duration");
        calc.var.setVarN(scanner.nextInt());

        calc.getPay();
    }
}
```

PS: Try your assignments by yourself.

Comment: We are a question-and-answer site, not a homework writing service.  Please do not give users reason to believe otherwise.  Thank you.

Comment: @JoeC I do not find reason to downvote my answer. Could you please explain?

Comment: As I said, we are a question-and-answer site, not a homework writing service.  Answers of the "copy, paste, and hand this to your instructor" variety (such as this) are just as subject to downvotes as the question itself.